# HttpClient never sends request on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, reverse-proxy

I have a weird problem and tried all sorts of things to get this to work.

I have a Reverse Proxy delegating handler in my Web API project that is wired up to intercept requests for internal resources, files and such, from our external site to an internal site inside our DMZ...

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Resources.API
{
    public class ProxyHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var routes = new[]{
                "/api/videos",
                "/api/documents"
            };

            // check whether we need to proxy this request
            var passThrough = !routes.Any(route => request.RequestUri.LocalPath.StartsWith(route));
            if (passThrough)
                return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            // got a hit forward the request to the proxy Web API
            return await ForwardRequest(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ForwardRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Clone the request and forward to the internal proxy site
            var proxyUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUrl"];
            var baseUri = new UriBuilder(proxyUrl);

            //clone the requestUri and point it at the proxy site
            var forwardedUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri)
            {
                Scheme = baseUri.Scheme,
                Host = baseUri.Host,
                Port = baseUri.Port
            };

            var forwardRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(request.Method, forwardedUri.Uri);

            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post || request.Method == HttpMethod.Put)
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                await request.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                forwardRequest.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

                //copy the content headers
                foreach (var header in request.Content.Headers)
                {
                    forwardRequest.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            };

            forwardRequest.Version = request.Version;

            foreach (var prop in request.Properties)
            {
                forwardRequest.Properties.Add(prop);
            }

            foreach (var header in request.Headers)
            {
                forwardRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(), disposeHandler: false);
            var task = await Task.Factory
               .StartNew(async () => await client.SendAsync(forwardRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                   cancellationToken),
                   CancellationToken.None,
                   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                   TaskScheduler.Default);
            try
            {
                task.Wait(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Content =
                        new ObjectContent<HttpError>(new HttpError(e, includeErrorDetail: true),
                            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
                };
            }

            return task.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Also tried awaiting and returning the task...

```
            try
            {
                return await task;
            }
```

This works fine on IIS Express 8.0 but not in IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Professional (my dev machine) or IIS 8.0 on Windows Server 2012.

The created `HttpClient` never actually sends the request over the network (checked by Fiddler) and eventually times out and throws an `AggregateException` with a child `TaskCanceledException`.

Setting a breakpoint on the `task.Wait`, I notice that, for some reason, the breakpoint gets hit **10** times, rather than once when running via IIS Express.

I've tried all sorts of stuff to try and get this to work including lots of searching Google and SO but nothing seems to be working.

Anyone know why this happens? or can explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you starting a Task to call the already asynchronous SendAsync method? You could simply write `var response=client.SendAsync(...);return response;` or even `return client.SendAsync(...)` if you don't care to check the response. You could also change all `return await xyz()` lines to `return xyz();`. If the parent method returns a Task created by another method, there's no need to wait for it to complete

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think I tried that initially but tried it again anyway. `return await client.SendAsync(...)` works in IIS Express 8.0 but not IIS 7.5 - still doesn't send the request and eventually times out. Is there something fundamentally different between the two environments that I'm missing???

Comment: No, apart from Express being a developer-only version. Instead of looking for obscure bugs though, try to clean up the code and then debug it. Another possibility is that you are hitting the two concurrent requests per domain limit. Or you may be redirecting the calls to the server itself, essentially creating an infinite recursion. Add logging or use the Parallel Stacks Debug Window to see *what* is going on when the breakpoint gets hit the Nth time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Never heard of the Parallel Stacks Debug Window before you mentioned it. Sweet! Did manage to figure out what was going on though.

Comment: Wow, 2 years later and somebody decided to downvote. WTF!

Comment: probably someone who doesn't know about the HOST header, or how they can be used to server multiple sites on port 80. Anyway, answer upvotes count more than question downvotes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to change the `Host` header on the request for it to be sent correctly. It was essentially ignoring the RequestUri and using the `Host` header to decide where to actually send the request.

```
forwardRequest.Headers.Host = forwardRequest.RequestUri.Host;
```

Now works like a charm and IIS will now send the request appropriately. Still leaves me wondering why IIS Express doesn't seem to need the `Host` header changing though!

The full code... Added the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Host` as well for good measure.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Resources.API
{
    public class ProxyHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var routes = new[]{
                "/api/videos",
                "/api/documents"
            };

            // check whether we need to proxy this request
            var passThrough = !routes.Any(route => request.RequestUri.LocalPath.StartsWith(route));
            if (passThrough)
                return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            // got a hit forward the request to the proxy Web API
            //return GetResponseFromProxy(request);

            //Nicer method using HttpClient - but it doesn't work on IIS!
            return await ForwardRequest(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ForwardRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Clone the request and forward to the internal proxy site
            var proxyUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUrl"];
            var baseUri = new UriBuilder(proxyUrl);

            //clone the requestUri and point it at the proxy site
            var forwardedUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri)
            {
                Scheme = baseUri.Scheme,
                Host = baseUri.Host,
                Port = baseUri.Port
            };

            var forwardRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(request.Method, forwardedUri.Uri);

            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post || request.Method == HttpMethod.Put)
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                await request.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                forwardRequest.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

                //copy the content headers
                foreach (var header in request.Content.Headers)
                {
                    forwardRequest.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            };

            forwardRequest.Version = request.Version;

            foreach (var prop in request.Properties)
            {
                forwardRequest.Properties.Add(prop);
            }

            foreach (var header in request.Headers)
            {
                forwardRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            // Don't forget to change the Host header to refer to the proxy
            forwardRequest.Headers.Host = forwardRequest.RequestUri.Host;

            //Add the relevant X-Forwarded headers
            var xForwardedHost = request.Headers.Host;
            forwardRequest.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-Host", xForwardedHost);

            var xForwardedFor = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            forwardRequest.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-For", xForwardedFor);

            var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(), disposeHandler: false);

            try
            {
                return await client.SendAsync(forwardRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
                    cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Content =
                        new ObjectContent<HttpError>(new HttpError(e, includeErrorDetail: true),
                            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because the HOST header has priority over the URL. The HOST header is used to server multiple sites over the same port. The different names are configures in DNS to point to the same IP. Web servers (including IIS) determine the correct site to hit by looking at the HOST header. That's how hosters for example, can host multiple sites on port 80 using the same machines